# Gradient not working with position:absolute

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get a linear gradient working as the background of my page. The gradient is not showing at all, and the background remains white. Here's the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        width:100%;
        margin-left:-50%;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1%, rgb(21, 126, 250) 99%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1%, rgb(21, 126, 250) 99%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1%, rgb(21, 126, 250) 99%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1%, rgb(21, 126, 250) 99%);
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 1%, rgb(21, 126, 250) 99%);

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    This is a test and a bad one at that.

</body>
</html>
```

Now if I remove the `position:absolute`, the gradient works. What am I doing wrong? I need to have that `position:absolute`, so what can I do?

**Edit**: tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Why do you need the body tag to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: Because this example is minimal for the sake of being concise and my CSS is in fact more complex than this.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't set body absolute. Can't you get the same with relative ?

Comment: It's a bit unusual to have the body tag absolutely positioned (and I'm not sure the benefit).  If you put the text inside another container and position it, then you should be good to go.  Don't forget to give the element some dimensionality (with a height property and display:block)

Comment: Yup, that seems to work, thanks a lot. I don't quite like having to use a redundant div, and I still don't see what's wrong with my code, but I'll go with this if there's no better alternative. Thanks again.

Comment: do you want the gradient to fade from top to bottom, or repeat like it does when you remove absolute?

Comment: Fade from top to bottom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do not set an html background, body's background is applyed to HTML.

Since body is in absolute, it has a 0 size for HTML and it doesn't trigger anything for HTML layout.

try to apply:`html {height:100%;}` 
and see what it does : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGApK

Comment: I still don't understand why the body doesn't get the background gradient applied - why do you have to involve the containing <html> element?

Comment: when you make `body` `absolute`, it gives `html` no height. `absolute` elements' height isn't included as part of the height of their parents. Normally you would see the `overflow`, but making `body` `absolute` can cause it's own set of issues. That's why everyone was asking why this isn't a `div` inside of `body` instead; they were probably wondering why you would want to add extra issues to sort out.

Answer (score 4):

**that's easy**

you just need to add `background-attachment: fixed !important;` to `body` and/or `height:100%` to `html`.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/NA7a6/

Though either option switches the background from `body` to `html`, so it may be a better solution to put the background on `html` directly, since it's going to go there regardless.

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/nRLNb/

Answer (score -1):

You can just add `position: relative;` to the parent element, in your case its the html tag.

```
html{
  position: relative;
}
```